# Android webview pinch zoom Problem

Tags: android, image, webview, zooming, pinch

Hi guyz im able to pinch zoom the image in webview its working properly. Zoom in is working fine but problem is zoom out. Image goes small and small.  How can i limit zoom out to the size of the image?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);  
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```